# How could avoid these terminal errors for ionic installation?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I formatted my computer because I had accidentally installed ionic with sudo. Now, I installed Catalina from the beginning and installed Node.js again. Although, I still face a problem installing ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a node version manager like NVM: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?

Otherwise, NPM has details on how to resolve the EACCES error:
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 0):

Seems like youre not running the command with sudo permission, can you try to run with prefix sudo? if this doesn't work, verify if you have the permission granted to access these folders.